# TextFileStreaming in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have many text file in local directory. Spark Program to read all the files and store it into database. For the moment, trying to read the files using text file stream not working.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream

/**
  * Main Program
  */
object SparkMain extends App {

  // Create a SparkContext to initialize Spark
  val sparkConf: SparkConf =
    new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("TestProgram")

  // Create a spark streaming context with windows period 2 sec
  val ssc: StreamingContext =
    new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

  // Create text file stream
  val sourceDir: String = "D:\\tmpDir"
  val stream: DStream[String] = ssc.textFileStream(sourceDir)

  case class TextLine(line: String)

  val lineRdd: DStream[TextLine] = stream.map(TextLine)

  lineRdd.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    rdd.foreach(println)
  })

  // Start the computation
  ssc.start()
  // Wait for the computation to terminate
  ssc.awaitTermination()
}
```

**Input:**

```
//1.txt
Hello World
```

Nothing print when stream the streaming. What is wrong in it?

Comment: mv 1.txt to some other directory. start the app, then move back 1.txt to the source directory.

Comment: Did you created or moved any new files after you started streaming?

Comment: I tried with starting stream without file then moved file into directory. nothing changed. still streaming not picking the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextFileStreaming` does not read the file that is already present in the directory. Start the program and create a new file or move the file from any other directory. The following program is simple word count for text file streaming

```
  val sourceDir: String = "path to streaming directory"
  val stream: DStream[String] = streamingContext.textFileStream(sourceDir)

  case class TextLine(line: String)

  val lineRdd: DStream[TextLine] = stream.map(TextLine)

  lineRdd.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    val words = rdd.flatMap(rdd => rdd.line.split(" "))
    val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
    val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)

    println("=====================")
    wordCounts.foreach(println)
    println("=====================" + rdd.count())
  })
```

The ouput should be something like this

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
=====================0
+++++++++++++++++++++++
(are,1)
(you,1)
(how,1)
(hello,1)
(doing,1)
=====================5
+++++++++++++++++++++++
=====================0
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried the same, but no help. i am trying to start streaming windows machine local mode and my project in `D:\SampleSpark` location and my file path `D:\tmpDir`. still not reading the file. i tried stream without file then moved file from other folder and with file then moved next file. :(

Comment: Np, i will test the same with Linux environment. first time exploring the text file streaming. if my understanding correct, text file stream only pick the file type `.txt` or it will pick any type ?

Comment: yes, i am able to run kafka streaming local mode successfully and store as csv file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166622/discussion-between-rumesh-krish-and-shankar-koirala).